# type number is storing upto 10 character in sails-mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am using SailsJS with MongoDB and model is having type number as below:

```
attributes: {
    mobile_no: {
      type: 'number'
    }
}
```

So when I insert with API it is working perfectly up to 10 numeric character length.

For more than 10+ numeric character length my document's field is automatically gets converted to float and adds decimal points something like `12345678902.0` but I don't want that because `mobile_no` field can have more than 10 characters.

Comment: Mobile "numbers" (and other communication "numbers") should be character fields - if you ever have to cater for leading "0", you're busted.

Comment: You should normaly store mobile numbers as `strings`

Comment: Phone numbers, credit card numbers, etc. are logically strings.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this problem is, you should write a migration script and convert all the mobile_no data to `string` format.

Comment: Thank you guys for clearing my doubt

Comment: but MongoDB is displaying int32, int64 in the field type, Why I can't do int64 ?

Comment: JavaScript’s only number type was double-precision floating point for a long time, with some operations on 32-bit integers. `BigInt` exists now, but MongoDB (and MongoDB drivers for Node) predates it, so any int64s you get from Mongo are losing precision.